# When selected empty value select second input

Tags: jquery

I have 2 input selected, selected curreny and po, when satrt loading po will disable and curreny will balnk value. If i pick select curreny, the po will show up base on curreny. But my problem is, when i picked the po, then i change curreny he selected value on po not empty or blank. What i need when i change curreny on value po will blank or empty, how i used that?? Any help?? This sample code i used it.

```
$('#currency').change(function () {
            var curr = $(this).val();
            $("#po option[value='']").attr('selected', true);
            if(curr!="")
            {
                $('#po').prop('disabled', false);


                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: host+"buypo/listpo",
                    data: {
                        'curr': curr
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log($("#po").html(data));
                    } 
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('#po').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
```

edit

i try used this code `$("#po option[value='']").attr('selected', true);` but nothing change it

Edit again :

I forgot to sayin this, in po input i used select2 or `class='js-example-basic-multiple'`. So is not normally select type.

UPDATE: Now i figure out!!!!
I use this code on even change on curreny

```
$('#select2-po-container').empty();
```

is work prefectly!!!! Cause i need to clear the sapn on select2 PO.

tq for all to help me this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use set to select item

```
$("#po").val("");
```

Comment: Is not wroking. :/

Comment: The issue is you are setting $("#po").val(""); before loading the po's content you can set the selected after setting the loaded po's items, or you have to always set the 1st option as empty to the po before do the ajax call to load and after loading append the items...

Comment: Well i edit my question. I forogt, my select not normaly select, but i use select2 or js-example-basic-multiple. So not working.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help?

On `change` of `currency` find the `first` option (assumed to be default) and `trigger` click event which will make it `selected` as well.

```
$("select#po option:first").click();
```

Comment: I forgot my select not select normaly, i use select2. on PO

Comment: thats why it is always better to add working fiddle. atleast add your htmls